# PHP проблема с use

Tags: php, классы

Пытаюсь использовать файл который находится в директории RakLib/src/server/ServerSocket.php

Есть файл main.php который находится рядом с папкой RakLib.
В main.php такой код:

```
<?php

use RakLib\src\server\ServerSocket;

$var = new ServerSocket("0.0.0.0", 2000, 8);
```

Но при запуске main.php случается ошибка:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "RakLib\src\server\ServerSocket" not found in /home/root/test/Deaf/main.php:7
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown in /home/root/test/Deaf/main.php on line 7
```

Если нужно, прикреплю код ServerSocket.php

Comment: А почему вы считаете, что достаточно файл расположить где-то и использовать `use`? Про автозагрузку знаете?

Comment: Про автозагрузку знаю. Просто не знаю что и как использовать. Кроме того, в ServerSocket.php есть namespace (щас увидел)

Comment: ну вот почитайте про автозагрузку для начала.... с помощью spl_autoload_register или composer

Comment: без банального подключения файла с классом в том месте, где он используется - ничего работать не будет..... просто `use` написать - недостаточно. В PHP так не работает

Comment: Ваш ответ помог, благодарю.